# Pointer-to-array, malloc, and out-of-bounds access

Tags: c, pointer-to-array, array-pointer

Given a pointer-to-array in C, can we malloc to it enough memory for extra elements (beyond the specified array size) and then safely access those elements using either the [] operator or pointer arithmetic?

Consider this example:

```
int (*foo)[ 10 ]; //Declare pointer to array of ten ints
foo = malloc( sizeof( int ) * 20 ); //Allocate memory for TWENTY ints
(*foo)[ 15 ] = 100; //Access element in "extra" space via [] operator 
*( *foo + 16 ) = 200; //Access element in "extra" space via pointer arithmetic
printf( "%d\n", *( *foo + 15 ) ); //Prints 100
printf( "%d\n", (*foo)[ 16 ] ); //Prints 200
```

This code compiles fine and produces correct results in gcc. However, I'm not sure if it invokes undefined behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: `foo[x]` is the same as `*(foo + x)`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you're reading/writing past the bounds of an array of `int` of size 10.

The proper way to access this memory is to use 2D array access.  So instead of this:

```
(*foo)[15] = 100;
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
foo[0][15] = 100;
```

Do this:

```
foo[1][5] = 100;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you sure the out-of-bounds access rule applies to the pointer arithmetic version?: ( *foo + n ). *foo + 0 decays to int pointer pointing the first element in the array. However, it's also an int pointer to the beginning of a malloced bloc of memory, which the the standards seem to treat as an "array object" and which I should - in theory - be able to move around inside freely using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: As for the proper/usual way, it's not quite relevant because the idea I'm exploring here is that pointers-to-array could be used to tack extra, compile-time information (specifically an integer value) onto what would otherwise be a regular pointer.

Comment: @JacksonAllan  The syntax `E1[E2]` is *exactly* equivalent to `*(E1 + E2)` so yes it applies.  As for arithmetic into the allocated memory, if you assigned the malloced memory to a `char *`, do arithmetic on that, then convert the resulting pointer to the desired type, that would probably be OK since a `char *` gets special treatment.

Answer (score 0):

I would allocate it a bit different way:

```
foo = malloc( sizeof( *foo ) * nrows );
```

it will  allocate 2D array having 10 clomns and `nrows` rowas.

The best way to access the array is using indexes

```
foo[row][column]
```